# How to check/uncheck a checkbox with onClick event on a button in React.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxForHamburger" />

      <Button onClick={??????}> UNCHECK </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have a Checkbox and a Button. I want the checkbox to be in "unchecked" state if the button is clicked.

What I tried-

```
<Button onClick={document.getElementById("checkboxForHamburger").checked = false}> UNCHECK </Button>
```

This is giving me an error - **Cannot set property 'checked' of null**

Comment: Make your checkbox controlled - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components. Accessing the dom directly is bad practice in react.

Comment: use state, don't go this way - it's not react

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you checkbox isn't controlled by a state value:

Let's start by adding a state:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);
```

Then we give the value to the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={checked} />
```

Then let's tell the button to toggle the checked state

```
<button onClick={() => {setChecked(old => !old)}}> {checked ? 'uncheck' : 'check'} </button>
```

Working example on [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bohr-2pivt)

Answer (score 2):

```
function MyApp() {
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
const handleCheck =() => {
 setChecked(!checked)
}
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} />
      <Button type="button" onClick={handleCheck}> Click Me </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        checked: true
    }
  }

  handleCheckbox = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({checked: false});
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleCheckbox}>Uncheck</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

#### Update

If you want to make the `checkbox` toggle by clicking the button then you can do this by changing the `handleCheckbox` function and button text.

```
  handleCheckbox = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
  }
```

And the button would be

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.handleCheckbox}>{this.state.checked ? 'Uncheck': 'Check'}</button>
```

Comment: I prefer to use functional components rather than class components

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
export default class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
  this.state={check:false};

   this.Toggle_checkbox=this.Toggle_checkbox.bind(this);
 }
  Toggle_checkbox=()=>{
this.setState({check:!this.state.check});
  }
 render(){
   return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.check} />

      <button onClick={this.Toggle_checkbox}> toggle </button>
    </div>
  );
}

 } 
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

check:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xrt6wa

Answer (score -1):

I just ran this error.

Do you want to run it like the code below?

```js
import React, { useState }  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function App() {
const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" value={value} id="checkboxForHamburger" />

      <Button onClick={() => setValue(!value)}> UNCHECK </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If the value is boolean, we can tell whether it is checked or not.

Comment: don't use state value directly.

Comment: In addition, if you want to distinguish between UNCHECK and CHECK, use the tricuspid operator to write the following together.

{value ? CHECK : UNCHECK}